# How to make a spam command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Ive just started learning py today and I want to make a spam command that uses args to choose

1. how many times to send the message
2. what the message is i want to spam

Ive tried taking peices of other code and bending them to what i need but now im stuck:

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(f'Connected to Discord!')

client.run('TOKEN HERE', bot=False)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
@bot.command(name='spam', help='Spams the input message for x number of times')
 async def spam(ctx, amount, message):
```

So my idea would be: .spam [amount of times] [message to spam]

thanks :)

(this is meant to be a selfbot but only to mess around with friends and stuff, im fully aware of the consequences of them but its just for fun)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.command(name='spam', help='Spams the input message for x number of times')
async def spam(ctx, amount:int, *, message):
    for i in range(amount): # Do the next thing amount times
        await ctx.send(message) # Sends message where command was called

bot.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

This defines a command that takes two arguments: an amount as integer and the message you want to send. `*,` Makes it so the rest of the command is put into message because otherwise it would stop at whitespace.

Example Usage: `.spam 2 Hello` Sends Hello two times.

You might run into [Rate Limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits) when overdoing this command so take care.

Comment: Ratelimits are handled internally by the library itself, also the ratelimit is pretty low, 5 requests per 5 seconds per channel iirc so there's no need to be worried about it

Comment: I've chaged the code to a working example for you, I suggest reading the official documentation for more help with commands: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score -1):

```
    @bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel = None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  if channel == None:
    channel = ctx.message.channel
  while True:
    await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
```

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question?